# How can I force a redraw of a process whoʼs parent is a panel-control?

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I've been tasked with creating an application launcher that hosts both Winforms and WPF applications and via a slightly different methodology Web applications. The user is presented with a list of applications they can launch and these are "captured" upon launch and are lodged inside a panel on a form by using SetParent to make the panel the parent of the processes MainWindowHandle. This bit appears to work well and the applications when launched are captured and displayed in the given panel.

What Iʼm having a particular issue with is that not all applications that are captured are happy to initially draw themselves in the panel. It seems to be isolated to those applications that are WPF based, but thatʼs not guaranteed.

Effectively what happens is that if a WPF application is launched, it is captured and moved to the panel, and the panel will remain blank until I click the panel at which point the application will happily repaint itself. From this point forward the application seems to be happy enough repainting itself as required without intervention.

Basically Iʼm now at my wits ends and have tried the following User32 native and .NET methods;
Invalidate (on the form, on the panel, on the tab control that hosts both of these)
Update
Refresh
SendMessage with a plethora of parameters, including attempting the, "you shouldnʼt do this" WM_PAINT.
RedrawWindow with the UpdateNow and Invalidate flags.

None of the above makes any visible difference and itʼs only when I physically click the panel or move the window that the contained application will behave and repaint itself.

Has anyone else produced anything similar and has a solution to the redraw/repaint issue? Iʼve scoured the entire Google/Bing/Duck Duck Go spheres trying to hunt down an answer but to no avail.

Hopefully one of you out there has an answer.

The following code represents the bulk of the feature in that it starts a process and captures the handle for the main window of the process and sets itsʼ parent to a panel control on a bog-standard WinForms window. I should probably point out that the bog-standard WinForms window is itself “hosted” inside an application using the ([EasyTabs](https://github.com/lstratman/EasyTabs)) Library. Which, I believe, is not causing any problems.

Example:

```cs
// Try to acquire a the process.
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);

try
{
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

    Process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    Process.Exited += TabManagerContainerForm_ProcessExited;

    Process.Start();

    if (Process != null)
    {
        // Wait until the process has created a main window or exited.
        while (Process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero && !Process.HasExited)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Process.Refresh();
        }

        if (!Process.HasExited) // We have acquired a MainWindowHandle
        {
            // Capture the Process's main window and show it inside the applicationPanel panel control.
            SetParent(Process.MainWindowHandle, applicationPanel.Handle);

            // Change the captured Process's window to one without the standard chrome. Itʼs provided by our tabbed application.
            SetWindowLong(Process.MainWindowHandle, (int)WindowLongFlags.GWL_STYLE, (int)WindowStyles.WS_VISIBLE); 
        }
        else // Process has exited.
        {
            if (Process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) Log.Information("{0} failed to execute.", Process.ProcessName);

            throw new FailedProcessException(string.Format("{0} failed to execute.", path));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Invalid path: {0}", path));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) when (!(ex is FailedProcessException)) // Catch everything but FailedProcessExceptions. FPEs are simply passed up the chain.
{
    Log.Error(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: If you give a code example of what you have done, it will be easier to understand where exactly you are stuck and need help. A long question with no specific example will not catch so much attention (maybe shorten the answer too).

Comment: I’ll see what I can do. Code wise it’s spread over several files and is not simple to dismantle. I’ll see if I can make a simpler POC example.

Comment: FYI: I tried another example using the standard WinForms tabs control and tab pages and got the same result. So it appears attempting to capture the main window of an process and embed it into a tab is a futile endeavour. There may be an answer, but for the moment it's not one I've been able to discover.

Comment: I updated my answer. It may have a solution to your tab problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:**

The problem seems to happen when attaching an application to a `Panel` in a tab that is not the currently visible tab.

**Solution:**

Add `WS_CHILD` flag to the call to `SetWindowLong`:

```
SetWindowLong(Process.MainWindowHandle, (int)WindowLongFlags.GWL_STYLE, (int)(WindowStyles.WS_VISIBLE | WindowStyles.WS_CHILD));
```

**Details:**

I tried reproducing the example in the question (without using [EasyTabs](https://github.com/lstratman/EasyTabs)). I used a simple `Form` with a single `Panel`. With a button press I call a simple WPF app and attach it to the `Panel`. It works OK, it renders immediately. The only problem I found was the position of the WPF window which was random. I fixed it with calling [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) (using [pinvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos)) like this:

```
SetWindowPos(Process.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.IgnoreResize);
```

Than, I tried using a `TabControl` with two tabs, each containing a `Panel` and two buttons, each one when pressed, launches a different WPF app to one of the `Panels`. I found that when a tab (`TabPage`) is not the visible tab, the problem occurs - the launched application is not visible until the `Panel` is clicked. I solved this problem by adding `WS_CHILD` flag to the call to `SetWindowLong`. I'm not sure why but it works...

My code:

```
// Capture the Process's main window and show it inside the applicationPanel panel control.
SetParent(Process.MainWindowHandle, applicationPanel.Handle);

// Change the captured Process's window to one without the standard chrome. Itʼs provided by our tabbed application.
SetWindowLong(Process.MainWindowHandle, (int)WindowLongFlags.GWL_STYLE, (int)(WindowStyles.WS_VISIBLE | WindowStyles.WS_CHILD));

// Change the Process's window position to the top-left corner of the panel
SetWindowPos(Process.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.IgnoreResize);
```

Comment: Thanks Eliahu. Appreciate your help on this. I tried out your suggestion and it does work. However thereʼs an issue now where WinForms applications launched in the same way no longer display. The WS_CHILD flag fixes the display for WPF applications but it causes the display of WinForms applications to break. In my case Iʼm using Notepad as my example WinForms application. One step forward, one step back.